# A simple Map and select React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to fetch 4 categories from my DB.

I get the category, everything is ok but when I submit my form, I get this data :

```
[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object]
```

Here the code :

```
//State
const [cates, setCates] = useState([]);

// Fetch 4 categories
useEffect(() => {
        const getCates = async () => {
          const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/categories");
          setCates(res.data);
        };
        getCates();
      }, [])

      //Map the categories from the State : cates
      const Categorie = cates.map((c) => (
            <option value={c.name}>{c.name}</option>

      ))
```

My component :

```
<Select>
    <option value="" hidden>Choisissez une catégorie</option>
    {Categorie}
</Select>
```

The console.log(Categorie) return an Array of object :

```
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0
: 
{$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: 'option', key: null, ref: null, props: {…}, …}
1
: 
{$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: 'option', key: null, ref: null, props: {…}, …}
2
: 
{$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: 'option', key: null, ref: null, props: {…}, …}
3
: 
{$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: 'option', key: null, ref: null, props: {…}, …}
length
: 
4
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array(0)
```

And the console.log(cates[0].name) give me the result I'm looking for.

But even when I try to put manually the categories like that : cates[0].name, cates[1].names etc... I get a blank page when I save my code and reload the page.

I just want to get my the categorie selected.

Comment: Do you keep track of what is selected? How do you submit the form?  Providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be nice.

Comment: I do in option onChange={e=> setCates(e.target.cates)}

Comment: What is the value of `e.target.cates`? See [React documentation on forms](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag).

Comment: Is there a selected state

Answer (score 0):

I can see the `Categorie` return an array of react components, not the data you fetch from the API
So you can write like this

```
const Component = () => {
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const getCates = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/categories");
      setCategories(res.data);
    };
    getCates();
  }, [])

  const List = () => {
    return categories.map(c => (
      <option value={c.name}>{c.name}</option>
    ))
  }

  return (
    <select>
      <option value="" hidden>Choisissez une catégorie</option>
      <List />
    </select>
  )
}
```

the List will be an array of react components, to use it just simply add `<List />`

Comment: I'll try it and if it's ok I valide your answer

Answer (score 0):

##### Hi @Romain Plantureux

You could try this as you disrobe in above.

And I notice that `<Select>` is not should be ***capital***. It's must like that `<select>`. Maybe that why your page showing blank.

[**Code Sandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-pond-krths0?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use React-styled components but it's same same

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem :

Code + comments :

//UseEffect + state (nothing changed, I just rename the const) :

```
//for saved the categorie I fecth.
const [cats, setCats] = useState([]);

// for save the value selected in my select : 
const [catSelect, setCatSelect] = useState("")

useEffect(() => {
  const getCats = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/categories");
    setCats(res.data);
  };
  getCats();
}, [])
```

The map component, I added a key :

```
const CatSelect = cats.map((c) => (
    <option key={c.name} value={c.name} >{c.name}</option>
 ))
```

And the most important changes on the Select :
(I use react-styled-components, this is why my Select have a Capital).

I have add the value='null'
For the OnChange, it save the value selected in a new state.

```
<Select value={null} onChange={e => setCatSelect(e.target.value)}>

    //This first option is important because the default value is not saved automatically in the new state... 
    <option value="" hidden> Votre choix</option>
    {CatSelect}
</Select>
```